# jose-jwt can generate JWT token via private key, but failed to valid token via RSA public key

Tags: authentication, jwt, rsa, private-key, public-key

I was trying to implement JWT authentication based on [jose-jwt](https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt) for .NET, I can generate JWT token by RSA private key successfully, and pass checking on https://jwt.io debugger, but I'm getting stuck on validating the token with RSA public key by the following error message:

> `RsaUsingSha alg expects key to be of AsymmetricAlgorithm type.`

Here is my steps and code snippets：

1. create PKCS#12 and certificate file

> ```
> openssl x509 -signkey jwt-auth-private.key -in jwt-auth-csr.csr -req -days 365 -out jwt-auth-certificate.crt
> openssl pkcs12 -inkey jwt-auth-private.key -in jwt-auth-certificate.crt -export -CSP "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -out jwt-auth-pkcs12.pfx
> ```

2. Create JWT token with RSA private key (It works)

> ```
> var pfxFilePath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", baseDir, "jwt-auth-pkcs12.pfx");
> var cipher = "private-key-cipher";
> var privateKey = new X509Certificate2(pfxFilePath, cipher, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet).PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
> var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
> {
>     { "sub", "mr.x@contoso.com" },
>     { "exp", 1300819380 }
> };
> token = Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, privateKey, JwsAlgorithm.RS256);
> ```

3. Valid token with public key (Failed)

> ```
> var crtFilePath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", baseDir, "jwt-auth-certificate.crt");
> var cipher = "private-key-cipher";
> var publicKey = new X509Certificate2(crtFilePath, cipher).GetPublicKey();
> var data = Jose.JWT.Decode(token, publicKey);
> ```

When I tried to decode token, I got an error message:

> `RsaUsingSha alg expects key to be of AsymmetricAlgorithm type.`

I had no idea on how to find what's wrong, please help. thanks.

Remark: It looks like that the .crt and .pfx file had no issues, cause if I use JWT.NET instead of jose-jwt libs, I can decode the token successfully in the same way.